# Scrape javascript data with requests return 404

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I want to scrape odds historical data from this page:
https://www.betexplorer.com/tennis/atp-singles/antwerp/fucsovics-marton-harris-lloyd-george/jebw7aKt/#ah

the data on the browser don't show until you hover the mouse cursor above the specific closing odd on the table
[image]

I tried finding the url which used by the website to fetch data from console:
[image]

but when using requests, it don't return required data:

```
u = "https://www.betexplorer.com/archive-odds/57k4hx4p6e6x9czds1a3/18/"
import requests
session = requests.Session()
r = session.get(u)     

print(r.status_code)
#return 404

print(r.text)
#return this: '\t\t<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">\n\t\t<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">\n\t\t\t<head>\n\t\t\t\t<base href="https://www.betexplorer.com/">\n\t\t\t\t<title>Betexplorer.com - Page not found</title>\n\t\t\t\t<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">\n\t\t\t\t<style type="text/css">\n\t\t\t\t\tbody {\n\t\t\t\t\t\tbackground-color: #505A60;\n\t\t\t\t\t\tcolor: #444444;\n\t\t\t\t\t\tmargin: 0; padding: 0;\n\t\t\t\t\t\tfont-size: 12px;\n\t\t\t\t\t\tfont-family: Tahoma, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;\n\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t\t#all {\n\t\t\t\t\t\tpadding-top: 1px;\n\t\t\t\t\t\tpadding-left: 10px;\n\t\t\t\t\t}\n\n\t\t\t\t\t#main {\n\t\t\t\t\t\twidth: 738px;\n\t\t\t\t\t\tpadding: 5px 5px 10px 15px;\n\t\t\t\t\t\tbackground-color:#F2F2F2;\n\t\t\t\t\t\tline-height: 20px;\n\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t\t#main h2 {\n\t\t\t\t\t\tmargin-top: 5px;\n\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t\t#footer {\n\t\t\t\t\t\twidth: 743px;\n\t\t\t\t\t\theight: 26px;\n\t\t\t\t\t\tpadding-left: 15px;\n\t\t\t\t\t\tpadding-top: 8px;\n\t\t\t\t\t\tbackground-color:#C7C7C7;\n\t\t\t\t\t\tfont-size: 11px;\n\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t</style>\n\t\t\t</head>\n\t\t\t<body>\n\t\t\t\t<div id="all">\n\t\t\t\t\t<div id="main">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<h2>Page not found</h2>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t\t\t\t<div id="footer">\n\t\t\t\t\t\tCopyright 2003-12 by BetExplorer.com\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t\t</body>\n\t\t</html>\n    '

r.json()
#return this error: JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 3 (char 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add referer in the headers

```py
import requests
headers = {
    'referer': 'https://www.betexplorer.com/tennis/atp-singles/antwerp/fucsovics-marton-harris-lloyd-george/jebw7aKt/',
}
response = requests.get('https://www.betexplorer.com/archive-odds/57k4hx2s5a4x0xds1a3/16/', headers=headers)
print(response.json())
```